# Is there any example where Calendar.current.date(byAdding will return nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I was puzzling on when will there be a case, where

```
Calendar.current.date(byAdding
```

will return `nil`?

I thought maybe such edge case might happen during day light saving. I wrote a sample code to give it a try. I run the below code in Playground

```
import UIKit

struct LocalDate: Equatable {
    let year: Int
    let month: Int
    let day: Int
}

struct LocalTime: Equatable, Codable {
    let hour: Int
    let minute: Int
}

extension Date {
    static func of(localDate: LocalDate, localTime: LocalTime) -> Date {
        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.year = localDate.year
        dateComponents.month = localDate.month
        dateComponents.day = localDate.day
        dateComponents.hour = localTime.hour
        dateComponents.minute = localTime.minute
        dateComponents.second = 0
        
        return Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
    }
   
    func adding(_ component: Calendar.Component, _ value: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: self)!
    }
}


// During 22 March 2021, Tehran will advance by 1 hour from 00:00 AM, to 01:00 AM.

let tehranTimeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Asia/Tehran")!
let oldDefault = NSTimeZone.default
NSTimeZone.default = tehranTimeZone
defer {
    NSTimeZone.default = oldDefault
}

let localDate = LocalDate(year: 2021, month: 3, day: 21)
let localTime = LocalTime(hour: 23, minute: 59)
let date = Date.of(localDate: localDate, localTime: localTime)
let tomorrow = date.adding(.minute, 1)

// Monday, March 22, 2021 at 1:00:00 AM Iran Daylight Time
print(tomorrow.description(with: .current))
```

Seems like `Calendar.current.date(byAdding` still able to work correctly, even when dealing with day light saving.

May I know, is there any example where `Calendar.current.date(byAdding` will return `nil`?

Comment: try adding something to `.distantFuture`

Answer (score 0):

Very rarely. Indeed even adding some time components to `.distantFuture` or detracting some to `.distantPast` most likely will return a data. Heck even adding a component which doesn't contain a time unit but a `Calendar` instance or a `TimeZone` instance will perform the operation by returning the same date specified as `to:` parameter.